# How to check whether Retrofit request call is finished or not?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, callback, retrofit, retrofit2

How can I figure it out whether my request call is executed or not?
In AsyncTask we simply check `(mPlaceObj.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)`
and it returns a boolean value.

on the other hand  in retrofit, we use the method `mCall.isExecuted()` ,  Returns true if this call has been either {@linkplain #execute() executed} or {@linkplain #enqueue(Callback) enqueued}.

So, is there any way to do it, please suggest?

Comment: onRespone callback. also you can check if the response is successful with isSuccessful.

Comment: If you are making call from another activity then you must use a callback interface to detect whether call has been finished.

Comment: can you post your retrofit code here so i can edit it

Comment: I just want to prevent multiple requests

Comment: @Manish ok i think callback will work for you

Comment: Any one found any good solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpLoggingInterceptor for check Retrofit request Call.

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
```

Use this logger with your retrofit Object like this:

```
Retrofit  retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(httpClient.build())
                    .build();
```

You'll get Logcat of your Request Call in Logcat Monitor. Trace it.

You will get two state using Retrofit i.e. onResponse & onFailure. If your call is Finished with Successfully then you find your call in onResponse & if there is an exception then your call in onFailure.

Refere this [tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/), you'll get more idea about retrofit & its functionality.

Use this dependency for Logger:

> compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.1'

Comment: @Lucifer Yes. Didn't this Help you!!?

Comment: what I am concern is, that Retrofit uses its own Thread mechanisam, So how can we get to know that if the it has completed successfully or not ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some task in another activity or another fragment after finishing retrofit call but your activity has changed and you are still waiting on the retrofit call to finish, you can use interface to send data.

Lets say you've an Activity A which is calling an API via retrofit, while this call is executing user has moved to another Activtiy B and now you need to call a method (or do something else) in Activity B upon the completion of the call from A.

Create an interface AB in A, implement AB and override its method in Activity B and call the method via an object of interface AB in activity A inside onResponse() method of the API call
.